# Visual Studio 2013 LightSwitch How to limit options in popup window when adding linked field data?

Tags: sql-server, input, visual-studio-2013, relationship, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have Visual Studio 2013 LightSwitch.  My app is deployed to Azure.  My SQL database is on Azure.  Tables and links are created and working.

Problem 1:  In Table A, when adding or updating data, I want to select data from fields in records based on primary key in other tables.  Add and update data works.  But my popup "X" list is way too long.  I want the popup "X" when adding or updating record in Table A to only give me the choice of records from Table B that matches the data I entered in a previous field in Table A, not all the records from Table B.

Problem 2:  Then while adding or updating Table A, I want the data from certain fields of the selected record in Table B to be transferred to certain fields in Table A.  (Let's say - If I select "ABC" from the popup "X" in Field 2 in Table A, then when I am selecting something from the popup "X" in Field 3 in Table A, I want to select only from the records in Table B that match "ABC" in the primary key field of Table B, not all the records.

Problem 3:  If the popup "X" list doesn't include the necessary record to put in Table A, then I want to add a record in Table B to include it in the popup list.

Problem 4:  How do I get my popup "X" list to include more than one field?  Is creating a new combined field the preferred way?

Problem 4:  I also need some good help with user text input and getting the text into my online database.  The thought of using an Intrinsic Database gives me the willies.

In your detailed solution, remember I am more familiar with Visual Basic than C#.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by popup X list but I'm going to assume you mean an Auto Complete Box control as that would be the default control for linked data. To achieve what you want for problem 1, you need to create a query on Table B with a parameter for the selection field of Table A. You then assign that query to the Auto Complete Box by changing its Choices setting from Auto to your new query. Changing your selection on Table A automatically filters the available selections in your query on Table B.

Beth Massi explains in detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/09/15/filtering-lookup-lists-with-large-amounts-of-data-on-data-entry-screens.aspx) - there isn't much code involved but her examples are in VB. I'd figure out problem 1 first and then see if that helps clarify the remaining ones.

Comment: Thank you.  As soon as I have time, I will try this.  And yes, it think you could call it an Auto Complete Box.  I just know a popup comes up when I click on the "X".  Thanks for reading my mind.